# How to set series Z-Order in Chart

Tags: c#, vb.net, charts, mschart

I have a Chart Control (System.Windows.Form.DataVisualisation.Charting, so WinForms) with multiple series, some are assigned to the primary, and some to the secondary Y-axis.

I need the chart to draw the series in a specific Z-order (meaning which series is drawn first, second, and so on), because some of them are overlapping. I can't find any related property.

I thought the z-order would depend on the order in which the series are added to the SeriesCollection, but this doesn't seem to change anything in my tests.

Am I missing something?

PS: It's not a 3D-Graph. So I am only asking about the order in which the different series are drawn.

Answer (score 9):

The series are drawn in the order they are placed into the Chart.Series collection.  Therefore you can automatically send new series to the back by using an `Insert` instead of an `Add`:

```
myChart1.Series.Add(myNewSeries1); // Draws this series on top of the others.
myChart1.Series.Insert(0, myNewSeries2); // Draw this series behind the others.
```

The following could be converted to an extension method for the chart control and (along with other methods e.g. BringToFront) could then be used in setting the order of series.

```
public void SendToBack(Series s)
{
    if (myChart1.Series.Contains(s))
    {
        myChart1.Series.Remove(s);
        myChart1.Series.Insert(0, s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The series are drawn in the order in which they are added to the `Chart.Series` collection. Add the one you want drawn on top as the last element in the collection.